# Decimal error on using linq function datacolumn

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a simple code that runs through all the text columns of a DataGrid. I use a for the create a LINQ statement that searches values on that column.

The problem I have is when the column has decimal values. I intent to make an if function asking if this column is decimal before going into the code. How can I check to see what column datatype it is?

```
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.DisplayMemberPath) = False AndAlso mBindingListCollectionView IsNot Nothing AndAlso editableTextBox IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim str As New StringBuilder

        For Each item As DataGridTextColumn In Me.Columns
            Dim b As Binding = item.Binding
            If b IsNot Nothing AndAlso b.Path IsNot Nothing Then
                str.Append(" " & b.Path.Path & " LIKE '%" & editableTextBox.Text & "%' OR")
            End If
        Next

        Dim query As String
        If str.ToString.Trim.EndsWith("OR") Then
            query = str.ToString(0, str.Length - 2)
        Else
            query = str.ToString
        End If
        mBindingListCollectionView.CustomFilter = query
```

This is a CustomControl in WPF. The Customcontrol allows me to add datacolumns and then i hook up an itemsSource in my window. When I start typing, this little function searches all the columns available and sees what I have similar to the entered text.

Comment: Is it not easier to find the datatype of the property that that column is bound to?

Comment: Yes! How Can this be done?

Comment: What is the datasource/itemssource for your datagrid?

Comment: @user3524375 This is *not* LINQ. This is data expressions. Btw, is this winforms or WPF or what?

Comment: Bjorn, i could be wrong, but i am pretty sure its linq. considering that i am using query. The exception I get is on adding the query to the customFilter.

Comment: @user3524375 You may, but *not* in the code you've provided. Look at this link: [LINQ query examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx). Do you see any resemblance? This looks like [data expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ok, point taken. but still, how can i remove decimal column types from the list?

Comment: Without knowing the datagrid's itemssource I don't think its going to be possible as a DatagridTextColumn is just a string representation of the underlining property and therefore doesn't really have a type (unlike a datatable for example)